# How to find by reference nested value using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to query by a reference value. I have the following Models:

```
//Room Model
const RoomSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  status: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Room', RoomSchema);
```

and the RoomUser Model which is referencing my Room model:

```
//RoomUserModel
const RoomUserSchema = new Schema({
    user : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    room: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room'},
    status: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RoomUser', RoomUserSchema);
```

What I want to do is to get a result finding by reference room name like this

```
const roomUsers = await RoomUser.find({'room.name' : 'ROOM_NAME_001'}, function(err) {
     //TODO
}).populate('user').populate('room');
```

But I don't get anything after that, just an empty [].

Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong and which is the correct way to do it?

Regards! =)

Answer (score 0):

There could be two ways of doing this.

Method 1: Using aggregate & lookup

```
db.RoomUser.aggregate(
  [
    { 
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Room",
            "localField": "room",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "rooms"
        }
    },
    { 
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "user",
            "localField": "user",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "user"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "rooms.name": "ROOM_NAME_001" }},
  ],
  function(err, result) {
    // "rooms" is now filtered by name
  }
)
```

Method 2: Using mongoose populate:

```
RoomUser.find().populate({
      path: 'room',
    },
    {
        path: 'user'
    }).exec(function(err, roomuser) {
      roomuser = roomuser.filter(function(ru) {
        return ru.name == "ROOM_NAME_001";
      });
    });
```